# Can't get the tickstyle=full option tp work in my pstrick code

Tags: pstricks

This is probably something very small but it is driving me insane. I'm trying to obtain the full ticks in my frame (or the top option) but I can't get it done.

[image]

I want all the ticks to point inwards. I'm using four \psaxes lines to craft each axes individually:

> ```
> \psaxes[Dx=2.14286, xAxis=true, yAxis=false, labels=no, tickstyle=full](0,0)(15,0)
> \psaxes[Dx=2.14286, xAxis=true, yAxis=false, labels=no, tickstyle=full](0,10)(15,10)
>
> \psaxes[Dy=2,  xAxis=false, yAxis=true, tickstyle=top](0,0)(0,10)
> \psaxes[Dy=2,  xAxis=false, yAxis=true, tickstyle=top](15,0)(15,10)
> ```

I obtain, however, everytime, the same result as in the picture above. What could be going wrong?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.75}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-0.5)(15.5,10.5)%
\psaxes[axesstyle=frame,tickstyle=inner,ticksize=0 5pt,Dx=2,Dy=2](15,10)%
\psaxes[Dy=2,xAxis=false,ticks=none,ylabelPos=right,axesstyle=none](15,0)(15,10)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]